# How to compare two python environments?

Tags: python, environment

A common issue (for me at least) is ending up in a different python environment than I expected. Another common issue is finding an undocumented python environment requirement when replicating an environment on another system.

To help both of these situations my question is: what python code can be run inside each environment to determine how the two environments differ?

Is a comparison of python version, packages, and environment variables (my attempt below) enough?

```
import os
import pip
import platform

print("=== python version:")
print(platform.sys.version_info)

print("=== python packages:")
installed_packages = pip.get_installed_distributions()
installed_packages_list = sorted(["%s==%s" % (i.key, i.version)
     for i in installed_packages])
print(installed_packages_list)

print("=== environment variables:")
print(os.environ)
```

Comment: Isn't the Python version and `pip freeze` output enough? Technically the env *could* do things like set variables, but I don't think those are commonly thought to be included in what you need in order to replicate the env.